# Improve sed command to replace first instance of character and all following characters?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

Input:

```
<e1 name="file1" id="id1" anotherId="id2">
```

Desired output:

```
file1
```

I can get what I need with this:

```
echo '<e1 name="file1" id="id1" anotherId="id2">' | sed 's/\(.*name="\)\(.*\)\(".*\)/\2/' | sed 's/".*//'
```

Output: `file1`

I would like to improve the set of commands and remove the last pipe to sed if possible.  If I remove the last pipe to sed, I cannot get what I want:

```
echo '<e1 name="file1" id="id1" anotherId="id2">' | sed 's/\(.*name="\)\(.*\)\(".*\)/\2/'
```

Output:

```
file1" id="id1" anotherId="id2
```

As you can see sed is picking up the last quotation mark and not the first after file1.

Can someone help improve this command?

Comment: I should have added that attribute order may vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<e1 name="file1" id="id1" anotherId="id2">' |
  sed -n 's/.*name="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'
```

Or with GNU `grep` if built with PCRE support:

```
echo '<e1 name="file1" id="id1" anotherId="id2">' |
  grep -Po 'name="\K[^"]*'
```

Comment: Thank you; the sed example works perfectly even when the attributes are in a different order.

Answer (score 2):

#### sed

You could simplify it a bit with this version:

```
$ echo '<e1 name="file1" id="id1" anotherId="id2">' | \
   sed 's/.*name="\(.*\)" id.*/\1/'
```

You don't need to wrap everything with parens, only the things you're interested in saving for use later on, so you can remove.

#### grep

You can also use `grep`'s ability to use Perl's regular expression engine (PCRE):

```
$ echo '<e1 name="file1" id="id1" anotherId="id2">' | \
   grep -Po '(?<=name=")(\w+)(?=")'
```

This use's PCRE's ability to look ahead and lookbehind. The notation looks for a sequence of characters such as `"name="` *before* what we're looking for. This bit is doing this:

```
(?<=name=")
```

It then looks for a series of word characters, this is what we're actually looking for:

```
(\w+)
```

The last bit that's doing the lookahead is this:

```
(?=")
```

It's looking for a quotation mark (`"`) *after* what we're looking for.

#### awk

```
$ echo '<e1 name="file1" id="id1" anotherId="id2">' | \
   awk '{gsub("\"","");split($2,a,"="); print a[2]}'
```

This variant strings the double quotes (`"``) doing a global substitution:

```
gsub("\"","")
```

The remaining string would be this:

```
<e1 name=file1 id=id1 anotherId=id2>
```

So we can let `awk` split this as it normally would and the 2nd column would be the bit we're interested in getting. That would be `$2` to `awk`. So we could take that variable and then split it on equal signs (`=`).

```
split($2,a,"=");
```

This will split `$2`, and store the results in an array, `a`. Afterwords we can print the 2nd element in the array, this being everything on the right side of the equal sign from `$2`.

```
file1
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but the answer by @stephane-chazelas works better when the attributes are in a different order.

Comment: @phatypus - not a problem, showing other methods, they can be adapted depending on your ultimate need.